# Using Xcode security framework to parse asn1 format

Tags: c, macos, security, openssl, asn.1

I'd like to parse asn1 format under OS-X 10.11.

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't include openssl as part of their SDK anymore. instead, there's an internal package I was advised to use exposed in the following header :

```
SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SecAsn1Coder.h
```

Unfortunately, the API I needed to parse the asn1 file and extract a given field, seems very different from the original openssl API.

In openssl, the function "asn1parse" defined in include/openssl/asn1.h, gets a DER formatted file, decoding it and return output text that represent the asn1 tree.

In Apple implementation, I've found "SecAsn1Decode" that may provide the same functionality. The documentation says that the output argument (void *dest) is a pointer to "a template-specific struct allocated by the caller", but i don't understand what struct should I expect and how much memory should I allocate ?

perhaps you can help me understand how to use it. any references are welcome.

Comment: [Apple's Developer Tech Support recommends that if you want OpenSSL functionality](https://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2015/Jun/msg00025.html), you build your own version of the library and include it within your app.  Which is what I do in my own apps these days.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, thanks for pointing this out, but i've already found Apple alternative crypto framework to openssl in "CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h" where you have all sort of sha/hash calculations, and in order to fully end my dependency in sources that are outside the SDK, i need the asn1 parser. if it's doable, i'd like to know how.

Comment: You can look in ***`/Applications/.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecAsn1Templates.h`*** for th template constants. And there are lots of hits and example code when searching for [SecAsn1Decode site:apple.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=SecAsn1Decode+site%3Aapple.com). You can probably refine it further with ***`filetype:c`***.

Comment: @jww, thanks for the help, I've looked at the template constants but i'm wondering how do i get the template per field i wish to extract. Well, I guess i'll have to figure it out prior to calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are now several snippets on GitHub showing how to call the `SecAsn1Decode` function, [see here for example](https://gist.github.com/sazameki/3026845):

```
typedef struct {
    size_t          length;
    unsigned char   *data;
} ASN1_Data;

typedef struct {
    ASN1_Data type;     // INTEGER
    ASN1_Data version;  // INTEGER
    ASN1_Data value;    // OCTET STRING
} RVNReceiptAttribute;

typedef struct {
    RVNReceiptAttribute **attrs;
} RVNReceiptPayload;

// ASN.1 receipt attribute template
static const SecAsn1Template kReceiptAttributeTemplate[] = {
    { SEC_ASN1_SEQUENCE, 0, NULL, sizeof(RVNReceiptAttribute) },
    { SEC_ASN1_INTEGER, offsetof(RVNReceiptAttribute, type), NULL, 0 },
    { SEC_ASN1_INTEGER, offsetof(RVNReceiptAttribute, version), NULL, 0 },
    { SEC_ASN1_OCTET_STRING, offsetof(RVNReceiptAttribute, value), NULL, 0 },
    { 0, 0, NULL, 0 }
};

// ASN.1 receipt template set
static const SecAsn1Template kSetOfReceiptAttributeTemplate[] = {
    { SEC_ASN1_SET_OF, 0, kReceiptAttributeTemplate, sizeof(RVNReceiptPayload) },
    { 0, 0, NULL, 0 }
};
```

And later:

```
NSData *payloadData = …
RVNReceiptPayload payload = { NULL };
status = SecAsn1Decode(asn1Decoder, payloadData.bytes, payloadData.length, kSetOfReceiptAttributeTemplate, &payload);
```

Comment: could I parse subsequence of data? For example, if data contains Integer, could I read this Integer only ( for example, first integer )?

Comment: @gaussblurinc Not a very elegant solution, but you could take the output from the 1st decode and pass it to the 2nd decode. 2nd decode could have your custom template to parse that integer.